# Python- pip install googleplaces

Tags: python, google-places-api

why am i getting error? while installing package for google places
i tried pip,easy_install and myenv but couldnt install

this is the error

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement googleplaces (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for googleplaces

Comment: Do you mean `pip install python-google-places`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package is `python-google-places`

Try this:

```
pip install python-google-places
```

Or

```
pip install https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places/zipball/master
```

See documentation for details:
https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places#installation

Answer (score 0):

Also pay attention that python3 requires its own pip for installing google places or any other library. I experienced such error :/